# How do I map to replace values in a dataframe from a multi-index series?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a series that looks like this:

```
EQTMAN        EQTDesc             EQTUnits
CARRIER       REFRIG UNIT         2646
CASE          COMBINE                2
              CORN HEAD            311
              CRAWLER DOZER          1
              PLANTER              331
              PLATFORM HEAD        870
              UTILITY TRACTOR        2
CAT           AUGER/DRILL            3
              CRAWLER DOZER          6
              ELEV SCRAPER          11
              ENGINE                 1
              EXCAVATOR             14
              LGP DOZER             12
              MOTOR GRADER           1
              TRACK SKID LDR         2
```

I can't figure out how to map these values from this multi-index table in order to replace values in a dataframe. Basically, for a row in dataframe I want it to replace values based on EQTMan and EQTDesc. So if a row's EQTMan = CASE and EQTDesc = PLANTER I want the EQTUnits column to be 331. Similarly, if EQTMan = CAT and EQTDesc = ENGINE, the EQTUnits should be 1.

It seems easy to map a more simple single-index set of series (called mappy) such as this:

```
EQTMan
ACME              10
ADVANCE            5
ASHLAND            6
BAD-BOY           23
BARKO              1
BEAU-ROC           2
BELL               2
```

To map this I was able to use df['EQTMan'].map(mappy) which worked just fine.

Thank you for any help in advance!

Comment: You can use merge, or set index and either combine_first or update.   If you add a complete reproducible example we can show you how.

Comment: Yes, I realized doing a merge is the way to go - thank you!